# How to call a toplevel function from a method or an extension function of the same signature?

Tags: kotlin

I use kotlin 1.1.2-2

I want to call top-level function `plus100(Int):Int` from method `Mul2.plus100(Int):Int`. I tried to do this in the following code but actually `Mul2.plus100` itself is called.

```
class Mul2 {
    fun plus100(v: Int): Int = plus100(2 * v)
}

fun plus100(v: Int): Int = v + 100

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val v = Mul2()
    println(v.plus100(10)) // expected: "120", actual: StackOverflowError
}
```

Is there anyway to access `plus100` from `Mul2.plus100`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the package the function is in to refer to it:

```
package pckg

fun plus100(v: Int): Int = v + 100

class Mul2 {
    fun plus100(v: Int): Int = pckg.plus100(2 * v)
}
```

You can also rename the function with an `import as` - this makes more sense if it's coming from another file or package, but works within a single file too:

```
package pckg

import pckg.plus100 as p100

fun plus100(v: Int): Int = v + 100

class Mul2 {
    fun plus100(v: Int): Int = p100(2 * v)
}
```

Comment: first, up-vote. there is another way that you can using  a variable ref a function.e.g: `val plus = ::plus100`

Comment: I suspect the first approach is not applicable if the package is global (empty)?